# Match everything expect a specific string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7 and have a question with regards to regular expressions. My string would be something like this...

```
"SecurityGroup:Pub HDP SG" 
"SecurityGroup:Group-Name" 
"SecurityGroup:TestName"
```

My regular expression looks something like below

```
[^S^e^c^r^i^t^y^G^r^o^u^p^:].*
```

The above seems to work but I have the feeling it is not very efficient and also if the string has the word "group" in it, that will fail as well...

What I am looking for is the output should find anything after the colon (`:`). I also thought I can do something like using group 2 as my match... but the problem with that is, if there are spaces in the name then I won't be able to get the correct name.

```
(SecurityGroup):(\w{1,})
```

Comment: If all of your strings always start with "SecurityGroup:", why not just remove the first 14 characters from each of them?

Comment: Show us a representing example of the input please.

Comment: If it's always "SecurityGroup" you don't really need regular expressions, you can just find that string with str.find() and take the string after.

Comment: Tip, use only one _negative_: `[^SecurityGroup:]`

Comment: Where is the `u` in your regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=SecurityGroup:)(.*)")
matches = re.findall(pattern, your_string)
```

Breaking it down:

```
  (?<=  # positive lookbehind. Matches things preceded by the following group
    SecurityGroup:  # pattern you want your matches preceded by
  )  # end positive lookbehind
  (  # start matching group
    .*  # any number of characters
  )  # end matching group
```

When tested on the string `"something something SecurityGroup:stuff and stuff"` it returns `matches = ['stuff and stuff']`.

**Edit:**

As mentioned in a comment, `pattern = re.compile(r"SecurityGroup:(.*)")` accomplishes the same thing. In this case you are matching the string `"SecurityGroup:"` followed by anything, but only returning the stuff that follows. This is probably more clear than my original example using lookbehind.

Comment: Why not simply `r"SecurityGroup:(.*)"`?

Comment: Good point, that looks like it would accomplish the same thing. But lookbehinds are cool! I guess not needed in this case though.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just do

```
security_string.split(':')[1]
```

To grab the second part of the String after the colon?

Comment: Regex is rarely the most Pythonic solution.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this:

```
([^:"]+[^\s](?="))
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/nT0tB5/2)